# Highlighting NSStatusItem with attributed string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstatusitem

I have a NSStatusItem, and I use an attributed string for it, setting is as such:

```
[statusItem setAttributedTitle:as];
```

where `as` is my attributed string. I use it to highlight certain parts of the item when certain conditions are met by coloring them differently. So my status item can have some red text and some black text, for example.

Now the problem is, when I use `setAttributedTitle` and then click on the status item, the colors don't get inverted as I want them to. For instance, when I used just `setTitle`, the text is black when not selected and changes to white when selected. Now it just keeps the color I set it to.

Is there a way to tell it to invert colors when it's selected? If not, how can I achieve this? Sorry, I'm a beginner in Objective-C.

Comment: Have you tried calling `setHighlightMode:YES`?

Comment: @jtbandes: yes, but that only controls the blue background when highlighted, it would seem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the only way to do this is:

- **do not set a menu** for the `statusItem` using `setMenu:`
- instead, use `setAction:`, change the color of the string, show the menu, and then change the color back

For instance, use something like:

```
[statusItem setAction:@selector(statusItemClicked)];
```

And implement the `statusItemClicked` method like this:

```
- (void) statusItemClicked {

  // change color of attributed string to its highlighted state here

  [statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:statusItemMenu]; // show the menu
                                                   // which used to be set
                                                   // using setMenu:

  // change color of attributed string back its non-highlighted state here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can implement the following NSMenuDelegate methods:

```
- (void) menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *) aMenu {
  // use an attributed string to set the title to your highlighted color
}


- (void) menuDidClose:(NSMenu *) aMenu {
  // use an attributed string to set the title black
}

[statusItem setMenu:[self menu]];
[[self menu] setDelegate:self];
```